# How to create a static model in Java?

Tags: java, swift

I am converting an app from Swift to android. I used a static class in swift to store the some data like this.

```
class Model {
   static let sharedModel = Model()
   var email = ""
   var password = ""

    struct receipts {        
        var image = UIImage()
        var currentDate = ""
    }

    var allreceipts = [receipts]()
```

In this case, when I needed to access or add data, I could just call

```
Model.sharedModel.allreceipts.add(Image,"12/2/2017")
Model.sharedModel.allreceipts[1]
```

How can I create a class which pretty much duplicates it in Java?

This is what I tried in Java

```
public class Model {
   static Model sharedModel = new Model();

   class Receipts {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String currentDate = "";
    }

    Receipts[] allreceipts;
  }
```

How Can I do the same thing in Java like I can in Swift where I could call this class from anywhere and access it?

Comment: I think you need to spend time reading the Oracle Java tutorial.  There are a few basic problems with your Java code.

Comment: I hope you noted that the solution that you accepted ... is basically doing all the things that I listed earlier on. Feel free to let me know if I can add something to my answer to get it at least into the range of "upvote worthy" in your eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there!

```
public class Model {
   public static Model sharedModel = new Model();

   public static class Receipts {
       private Bitmap image;
       private String currentDate = "";
   }

   public Receipts[] allreceipts;
}
```

The above is not the best practises, but it shows you how Swift and Java differ. First, I made the `internal` (without an access modifier) members in Swift `public`. This is because the default access level in Java is `package` and that is a little different from `internal`. I have also made the `Receipts` class `public static`. In Java, inner classes are non-static by default, so in order for them to be accessed like this: `Model.Receipts`, they need to be static.

Now let's change the code so that it follows Java conventions:

```
public class Model {
    private static Model instance = new Model();

    public static Model getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Receipts[] getAllReceipts() {
        return allreceipts;
    }

    public void setAllReceipts(Receipts[] allreceipts) {
        this.allreceipts = allreceipts;
    }

    public static class Receipts {
        private Bitmap image;
        private String currentDate = "";
    }

    private Receipts[] allReceipts;
}
```

In Swift, the singleton instance is usually called `shared`, but in Java we usually call it `instance`.

Java lacks the cool "properties" in Swift. You should make all member variables private and create getter and setter methods for them. In this case, `sharedModel` is declared with `let`, so it only gets a getter. `allReceipts` is a `var`, so it has both a getter and a setter.

Comment: Upvoted for the lengthy example - but please note: the deficiencies about this approach are still present in your code. Using a static instance like that, on which you fully set that complete array ... good enough for education purposes but as said: *good* OOP looks different.

Answer (score 2):

In almost the same matter:

- you have to make that inner class, *public* too
- same for its members, and the array `allReceipts`
- you make that array *static* as well

But note: that is typically not what a **good** model would do. If at all, you would be using a Singleton - and you would have a method to return that field - and nothing in there would be static (maybe except the method to fetch the singleton instance).

You see - your idea of a model leads to direct hard coupling between classes. Assuming you want to change something in here - you might to update *all* classes that are using it.

What you put here is the opposite of good OO design. You basically a "global" struct that programs then have to directly access. And then they read/write to that in an uncontrolled manner. That is how you would written a program in an imperative language like Pascal 25 years ago.

Good OOP is about encapsulation, information hiding, ...